# use kafka-producer-perf-test.sh how to set producer config at kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

```
bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --messages 1000000 --message-size 1000 --topics kafka_producertest_1replication_1partitions --broker-list mesos006:9092,mesos007:9092,mesos008:9092 --threads 1 --compression-codec 3 --batch-size 100000
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" kafka.common.InvalidConfigException: Batch size = 100000 can't be larger than queue size = 10000
        at kafka.producer.ProducerConfig$.validateBatchSize(ProducerConfig.scala:39)
        at kafka.producer.ProducerConfig$.validate(ProducerConfig.scala:29)
        at kafka.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.scala:116)
        at kafka.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.scala:56)
        at kafka.producer.OldProducer.<init>(BaseProducer.scala:59)
        at kafka.tools.ProducerPerformance$ProducerThread.<init>(ProducerPerformance.scala:210)
        at kafka.tools.ProducerPerformance$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcVI$sp(ProducerPerformance.scala:58)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
        at kafka.tools.ProducerPerformance$.main(ProducerPerformance.scala:57)
        at kafka.tools.ProducerPerformance.main(ProducerPerformance.scala)
```

config/producer.properties:

```
queue.buffering.max.messages=100000
```

When using kafka-producer-perf-test.sh, how to set all the parameters of the producer. Or give it a configuration file (for example: config/producer.properties)
how tow make config/producer.properties effect?

kafka-producer-perf-test.sh parameters

```
[root@mesos006 kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0]# bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh 
Missing required argument "[topics]"
Option                                  Description                            
------                                  -----------                            
--batch-size <Integer: size>            Number of messages to write in a       
                                          single batch. (default: 200)         
--broker-list <hostname:port,..,        REQUIRED: broker info (the list of     
  hostname:port>                          broker host and port for bootstrap.  
--compression-codec <Integer:           If set, messages are sent compressed   
  supported codec: NoCompressionCodec     (default: 0)                         
  as 0, GZIPCompressionCodec as 1,                                             
  SnappyCompressionCodec as 2,                                                 
  LZ4CompressionCodec as 3>                                                    
--csv-reporter-enabled                  If set, the CSV metrics reporter will  
                                          be enabled                           
--date-format <date format>             The date format to use for formatting  
                                          the time field. See java.text.       
                                          SimpleDateFormat for options.        
                                          (default: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS)   
--help                                  Print usage.                           
--hide-header                           If set, skips printing the header for  
                                          the stats                            
--initial-message-id <Integer: initial  The is used for generating test data,  
  message id>                             If set, messages will be tagged with 
                                          an ID and sent by producer starting  
                                          from this ID sequentially. Message   
                                          content will be String type and in   
                                          the form of 'Message:000...1:xxx...' 
--message-send-gap-ms <Integer:         If set, the send thread will wait for  
  message send time gap>                  specified time between two sends     
                                          (default: 0)                         
--message-size <Integer: size>          The size of each message. (default:    
                                          100)                                 
--messages <Long: count>                The number of messages to send or      
                                          consume (default:                    
                                          9223372036854775807)                 
--metrics-dir <metrics dictory>         If csv-reporter-enable is set, and     
                                          this parameter isset, the csv        
                                          metrics will be outputed here        
--new-producer                          Use the new producer implementation.   
--producer-num-retries <Integer>        The producer retries number (default:  
                                          3)                                   
--producer-retry-backoff-ms <Integer>   The producer retry backoff time in     
                                          milliseconds (default: 100)          
--reporting-interval <Integer: size>    Interval at which to print progress    
                                          info. (default: 5000)                
--request-num-acks <Integer>            Number of acks required for producer   
                                          request to complete (default: -1)    
--request-timeout-ms <Integer>          The produce request timeout in ms      
                                          (default: 3000)                      
--show-detailed-stats                   If set, stats are reported for each    
                                          reporting interval as configured by  
                                          reporting-interval                   
--sync                                  If set, messages are sent              
                                          synchronously.                       
--threads <Integer: number of threads>  Number of sending threads. (default: 1)
--topics <topic1,topic2..>              REQUIRED: The comma separated list of  
                                          topics to produce to                 
--vary-message-size                     If set, message size will vary up to   
                                          the given maximum.
```

Answer (score 10):

```
$bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic my_topic --num-records 50 --throughput 10 --producer-props bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer --record-size 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the documentation attached to the script you are using:

```
usage: producer-performance [-h] --topic TOPIC --num-records NUM-RECORDS [--payload-delimiter PAYLOAD-DELIMITER] --throughput THROUGHPUT
                            [--producer-props PROP-NAME=PROP-VALUE [PROP-NAME=PROP-VALUE ...]] [--producer.config CONFIG-FILE] (--record-size RECORD-SIZE | --payload-file PAYLOAD-FILE)

This tool is used to verify the producer performance.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help             show this help message and exit
  --topic TOPIC          produce messages to this topic
  --num-records NUM-RECORDS
                         number of messages to produce
  --payload-delimiter PAYLOAD-DELIMITER
                         provides delimiter to be used when --payload-file is  provided.  Defaults  to  new  line.  Note  that  this  parameter  will be ignored if --payload-file is not
                         provided. (default: \n)
  --throughput THROUGHPUT
                         throttle maximum message throughput to *approximately* THROUGHPUT messages/sec
  --producer-props PROP-NAME=PROP-VALUE [PROP-NAME=PROP-VALUE ...]
                         kafka producer related configuration properties like bootstrap.servers,client.id etc. These configs take precedence over those passed via --producer.config.
  --producer.config CONFIG-FILE
                         producer config properties file.

  either --record-size or --payload-file must be specified but not both.

  --record-size RECORD-SIZE
                         message size in bytes. Note that you must provide exactly one of --record-size or --payload-file.
  --payload-file PAYLOAD-FILE
                         file to read the message payloads from. This works only for  UTF-8  encoded  text  files.  Payloads  will  be read from this file and a payload will be randomly
                         selected when sending messages. Note that you must provide exactly one of --record-size or --payload-file.
```

I think the argument you are looking for is:

```
 --producer.config CONFIG-FILE
                         producer config properties file.
```

I have not tried it, but is worth to give it a try.

Comment: thank you for your reply.i use kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0, the documentation is not the same as yours,your version is 0.10 or higher version?

Comment: I am using a newer version, kafka_2.12-0.10.2.0. That is why our documentation does not match.